# How to have 2 functionality in one button, dynamically change functionality of the button click

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to have functionality in a button where first time I click it, it will create an element and the second time, it will change the properties of the element.

Comment: On click , check if the  element exists or not.

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: Take a look https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/JjXWeyV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
function create(el) {
  console.log('created');
  el.setAttribute('onclick', 'update(this)');
}

function update(el) {
  console.log('updated');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="create(this)">My Button</button>
```